# How to generate documents (doc / pdf) through a facebook chatbot?

Tags: forms, facebook-messenger-bot

How do I make my fb chatbot collect information from user and then, with that information, fill up a form, **generating a document (word / pdf)**, which then will be sent back to the user to download?

So far, I only can collect the info and send it to my email and fill up the form manually. I need it to be automatic.

Any hints will pe appreciated

Comment: What is the server side framework or language?

Comment: I'm using node.js